# Changing how Fabrik extension lists are displayed

Tags: articles, css, user, fabrik

I created a list using Fabrik and used elements to create fields for the list. The result was a form for my Joomla registered users to use to input data such as in fields I created like in the below picture (channel name, title, ...etc).

I let the website guests see (but not edit) the data that was inputted and the result was the photo I've attached below.

The problem: the way that information is displayed is not user-friendly (a guest has to click on the button to see the details).

Is there a way that I can change how things stored in the form are displayed? I want to share them as articles preferably, like every submission done through a list is changed to an article. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: It seems like you need a module for that. It might be possible though, but a module would offer you more possibilities and flexibility.

Comment: I guess you are looking for a custom template... either for the list or the details: [Form/Details Templates](http://www.fabrikar.com/forums/index.php?wiki/form-and-details-templates/) [List Templates](http://fabrikar.com/forums/index.php?wiki/creating-a-custom-list-template/)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try switching from the Bootstrap (default) template to the Div template layout instead, that will give you a "card like" layout, that will give the feel of an article blog layout.